# Gem dependency - how to limit output?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'd like to display required dependencies of a *specific* gem before installing.

```
gem dependency -r nokogiri
Gem nokogiri-1.6.0
...
Gem nokogiri-diff-0.2.0
...
Gem nokogiri-fitzsimmons-1.5.5.3
...
Gem nokogiri-happymapper-0.5.7
...
# etc. - many other gems & dependencies follow
```

How to limit output of `gem dep` to display only current nokogiri gem dependencies and nothing more ?
By the help to dependency command it accepts GEMNAME argument. Why it matches also other gems just starting with the same string ?
I've tried if regular expressions do work but f.E. `gem dep -r '^nokogiri$'` returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are generally enclosed in forward slashes.

```
$ gem dep -r /^nokogiri$/
Gem nokogiri-1.6.0
  hoe (~> 2.16, development)
  hoe-bundler (>= 1.1, development)
  hoe-debugging (>= 1.0.3, development)
  hoe-gemspec (>= 1.0, development)
  hoe-git (>= 1.4, development)
  mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
  minitest (~> 2.2.2, development)
  racc (>= 1.4.6, development)
  rake (>= 0.9, development)
  rake-compiler (~> 0.8.0, development)
  rdoc (~> 3.10, development)
  rexical (>= 1.0.5, development)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's a bit surprising as other commands like `query` or `search` do work *without* enclosing slashes only. Some inconsistency here.